# O que são Crosscuting contracts? Qual a relação com Design by contract?

Tags: java, metodologia

O que são *crosscuting contracts*? Qual a relação com *Design by contract*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Design by contract*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) (DbC) é uma abordagem para *design* de *software* que prevê a formalização de contratos (i.e, pré-condições, pós-condições e invariantes) entre clientes e fornecedores.

Linguagens como [Eiffel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_(programming_language)) (criada pelo [Professor Bertrand Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Meyer), que também cunhou o termo DbC) possuem suporte nativo a DbC. Em Eiffel podemos especificar contratos para rotinas e classes através de cláusulas como `require`, `ensure` e `invariant` (para mais informações veja [Eiffel Software: Building bug-free O-O software: An Introduction to Design by Contract™](https://www.eiffel.com/values/design-by-contract/introduction/)). Já em linguagens como Java o suporte nativo é limitado a [*assertions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html).

Técnicas de [Programação orientada a aspectos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_aspecto) (AOP) visam desacoplar *crosscuting concerns* (características transversais) da funcionalidade principal do sistema. Por exemplo, aspectos da aplicação como logs, controle transacional e segurança podem ser moduralizados com AOP, diminuindo assim a disperção do código necessário para garantir essas características através da aplicação.

Existem várias bibliotecas que tentam emular a noção de contratos através de AOP, por exemplo, o [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#programming-by-contract) tenta emular contratos no Java através do [AspectJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ).

No meio acadêmico existem discussões em aberto sobre a natureza dos contratos. Uma delas diz respeito a *crosscuting contracts*, ou seja contratos que englobam vários métodos / classes. Há aí naturalmente uma intersecção entre AOP e DbC.

Vários autores respeitados admitem a existência de *crosscuting contracts*. Essa é uma das linhas de pesquisa, por exemplo, do [Professor Henrique Rebêlo](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~hemr/) que criou a ferramenta [AspectJML](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~hemr/aspectjml/) para especificação de *crosscuting contracts*.

*Crosscuting contracts* permitem, em tese, maior reaproveitamento de código. Dito isso, existem controvérsias sobre a adequabilidade de aspectos para a implementação de DbC. Por exemplo, [essa publicação de 2005](http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/lncs/aspects_contracts.pdf) coautorada por Meyer coloca o casamento entre DbC e AOP em cheque. Por sua vez, [essa publicação de 2014](http://design.cs.iastate.edu/papers/AOSD-14/aosd14.pdf) (cujo primeiro autor é Rebêlo), tenta conciliar *trade-offs* entre linguagens com suporte nativo a DbC e AOP.